# How to customize delay in this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This piece of code appears to be responsible for an image slider on my website (it's currently not online). I would like to customize the delay between the slides. I tried changing the '5000' at the end to '10000', or '900000' or anything, but it has no effect whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
   var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 ); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe you have to change the animation speed two and try to log something in setInterval and see when its log and the duration

Comment: I don't think this will matter, but change `"slideSwitch()"` to `slideSwitch`

Answer (score 0):

i think you shold take away the Brackets

like:

```
setInterval( "slideSwitch", 5000 );
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ekesaw/5/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $img = $('#slideshow').find('img');
var C = 0;                    // COUNTER
var N = $img.length ;         // NUMBER OF IMAGES
var intv;                     // INTERVAL

$img.hide().eq( C ).show();   // PREPARE VISIBILITIES

function slideSwitch() {
  intv = setInterval(function(){
    $img.stop().fadeTo( 500, 0 ).eq( ++C % N ).stop( 1 ).fadeTo( 500, 1 );   
  },2000);
}

slideSwitch();                // RUN


// PAUSE ON MOUSEENTER :)   
$('#slideshow').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
  var isMEnt = e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval(intv) : slideSwitch();               
});
```